# Is it possible to set up a multi-boot system with SCCM?

Tags: sccm, sccm-2012

I'd like to have a single test computer that would have multiple images being used by my users, and whenever one of them is having issues with a particular image, I'd like to be able to boot into that particular image to debug the problem myself.

I'll admit that I don't have too much experience with SCCM.

What I would find ideal is if SCCM had some way of being able to install a bootloader and menu onto a computer, and then I would choose whichever OS images I want to go along with it.

The other option that I could think of is setting up an image that is already set up for multi-boot, although this would mean that there would have to be images for various combinations of the OS images.

I'm also open to other ideas for how to do this.

Comment: As this isn't directly answering your question, I'll post as a comment.  But this seems like a problem that virtual machines are a perfect solution for.  Don't hassle with getting your images to all multi-boot on the same physical machine.  Just get your images running as VMs on your host computer and start the one you need to troubleshoot when you need it.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @RyanBolger That would be more ideal (and, admittedly, something that slipped my mind as a solution), but it may not be possible where I'm working.  I'll definitely look into it.

Comment: It's possible, and not even that difficult, to use SCCM to deploy dual boot systems, so conceptually, it's possible to deploy multi-boot images to a machine using SCCM, but SCCM is probably not the tool you'd want to use to install the bootloader or boot menu.  Frankly, for a multi-boot system, you'd have to pre-partition the disk (I *thinki*), chain multiple task sequences together and then script up a way, or manually install a bootloader afterwards.  It just strikes me as being much more work than it would save you.

Comment: I agree with @hopelessn00b, possible,  but not the best way to go about it, and way more work than its worth. Great question though, but I would setup a hyper v box with test cm configurations, in fact, that's what I did :-)